# is it possible to enable WPS to connect to WiFi in Windows 10 using a script?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, bash-scripting, wifi-configuration, wps

Is there any way to connect to WiFi by enabling the WPS method, for example, from the cmd in Windows 10? I'd like to automate it in a script.